# How-To: Use the Graph API to Upload Photos to a user’s profile

Tags: php, html, facebook

I am developing an application which uploads images into user's profile.I manage to do this by referring this blog

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/

Everything works fine and display the 'id' of the uploaded image.

Now I want to take this id into a variable and pass it to another file without displaying 'id' of the
image(Lets say I want to pass this id into a.php file and display the 'id' using 'echo' command).

Can any one help me to do this? I think this is not a difficult task.Since I have vary poor knowledge about php, I cannot figure out any way.

Can any one please please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "pass into another php file?" If you mean reload the page but with passing the ID you can use $_GET array.

Simply, after receiving the id from uploaded photo you can call function:

```
header('location : http://yourdomain.com/a.php?id='.$id_of_photo);
```

and then in a.php you can get it by accessing $_GET array

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
  echo 'uploaded photo id is: '.$_GET['id'];
}
```

Comment: this is the code which upload the image into fb. 
<?php
echo '<html><body>';
         echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="'.$graph_url.'" method="POST" >';
         //some other codes 
         echo '</form>';
         echo '</body></html>';
?>
once I clicked the 'Upload' button it upload the image and dirrect me into graph api page and display the id of the image.

output{ "id": "1001207389476" }
But I need to pass this id into another file call a.php
insted of loading graph api page(Let says I want to display "Your photo id=".$id_of_photo //This code is placed in a.php file)

Comment: Maybe you should try to use facebook API for php? It have one usefull method named api(). This method will post your image without redirecting you to graph.facebook.com (it use http request)